Receiving AVError.Code.sessionNotRunning in AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate method after upgrading to iOS 18
I have following code which worked with no error before iOS 18.
I have class incapsulating photo shooting called PhotoCaptureManager, where I lazily init session when user goes to camera screen:
lazy var captureSession: AVCaptureSession? = {
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
    do {
        guard let videoDevice = self.currentVideoDevice else { return nil }
        let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)
        guard session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else { return nil}
        session.beginConfiguration()
        session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
        session.addOutput(photoOutput)
        session.sessionPreset = .photo
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return session
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}()

In CameraViewController viewDidAppear method I have a call to method which starts the captureSession:
private func setupCameraPreview() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.cameraPreview.videoPreviewLayer.session = self.cameraManager.capture.captureSession
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async { [weak self] in
            self?.cameraManager.capture.captureSession?.startRunning()
        }
    }
}

When user tap capture button the following code is executed:
func takePicture(_ completion: @escaping (_ imageData: Data?) -> Void) {
    takePictureCompletion = completion
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    photoOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)?.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation(by: UIDevice.current.orientation)
    photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}

Handling result in delegate methods:
extension DefaultPhotoCaptureManager: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

        if let error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        guard let jpegData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else { return }

        takePictureCompletion?(jpegData)
    }

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didCapturePhotoFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
        print(resolvedSettings)
    }
}

resolvedSettings are always printed as something like this:

<<<< AVCapturePhotoOutput >>>> Fig assert: "hasFigCaptureSession" at bail (AVCapturePhotoOutput.m:529) - (err=0)
<AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings: 0x30163d4a0 uid:3  photo:{0x0} time:nan-nan>

and error is

Optional
- some : Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11803 UserInfo={AVErrorRecordingFailureDomainKey=3

11803 code is AVError.Code.sessionNotRunning but if I check captureSession.isRunning is always true, and output.captureReadiness is always ready.
What helped me is it put this inside my takePicture method (and it doesn't matter if it's .speed or .quality:
if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
    photoOutput.maxPhotoQualityPrioritization = .speed
}

before
photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

It's written in docs that

Changing the maxPhotoQualityPrioritization while the session is running can result in a lengthy rebuild of the session in which video preview is disrupted.

But it seems it somehow inexplicably restarts session, but I wonder what happened in iOS 18 that I have to do it.
Does anyone else face the same problem?

Yes I'm facing the same thing starting with iOS 18. Almost same code as you. Photo capture works the first 1 or 2 times, then starts failing with the same error. Adding the maxPhotoQualityPrioritization setting didn't help for me.
I found that photo capture works as long as you stay in the same screen, but when you call session.stopRunning on viewWillDisappear to nav away, then startRunning on viewWillAppear, that's when it stops working. When you go to capture photo, it says the session isRunning is true, but there's the same error.
My fix so far is to remove session.stopRunning on viewWillDisappear so the camera output is getting continuously streamed. It's pretty awful, but better than it not working at all. I'll continue investigating for a better fix.
It still breaks if you change the device orientation and change the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation, but then I silently retry and it works again.

Have you tried the decision I mentioned with setting maxPhotoQualityPrioritization?
if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
photoOutput.maxPhotoQualityPrioritization = .speed
}

@AlexSh. Yes, I tried it but it didn't help for me. I found that removing session.stopRunning also didn't work 100% of the time. In the end, I added
self.session.beginConfiguration() self.session.commitConfiguration() right before capturing a photo, and that seems to fix 99% of the errors. It's interesting, I added analytics to when the errors appear, and looks like it's been happening since iOS 16.4. I think I'll end up migrating to Apple's new AVCam code eventually to see if that fixes it.
